# Use POST to submit form, but change action?

Tags: javascript, forms, http-post

I'm trying to submit a form with Java, which looks like this:

```
<form id="bForm" action="/a/b.php" method="POST"></form>
```

There are no `<input type="hidden">`, there are not even any `<input>` at all.
In the source, I see that this form is submitted when I click a link which
executes javascript code like this:

```
javascript:b(<k>,<v>)
```

where `<k>` and `<v>` is some key and value consisting of some numbers.

Now, the function `b()` in the source is this:

```
function b(value, key) {
        var form = document.getElementById('bForm');
        form.action = '/b/user/' + key + '/' + value + '.txt';
        form.submit();
}
```

What I'm trying to receive is the .txt file send as response, but trying to directly open

```
http://<url>.com/b/user/<key>/<value>.txt
```

in a browser does not get me the .txt file, but a message saying it has to be accessed by using the POST method.

Now, I read about how to send requests via POST (also from trying to find a
solution here) and think I understood most. Still, I only read about mostly everything today, including what forms are, so excuse me if the solution is obvious.
The problem I have here is that there are no parameters I can pass to "let the URL know" which action to do upon submitting the form.

Now as I can probably not change the action of the form, what do I do?
Can I somehow "connect" to the URL which leads to the .txt file via "POST"?
Or do I need to execute the javascript somehow, and if so how?

***Edit:*** I have solved the problem now, not sure if my explanation was not good enough, but the solution seemed pretty simple, I just didnt know enough about forms.
So, action=#myurl# means that the form is submitted to the #myurl#, not to the current page. And, although the target URL seems to point to some file which cannot do anything with the submitted form, this is not right. In fact, it points to a script, but the script is "hidden" in a way that we only see the path to the file we want to download in the URL.
So, I just did this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com/b/user/" + key + "/" + value + ".txt");
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//set User-Agent, Cookie, etc. properties here
c.setRequestMethod("POST");
c.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); //not sure if this is needed
InputStream in = c.getInputStream(); //this submits the parameter-less form
//now I can get the response with this stream, i.e. read & save the .txt file
```

All tested and running complete code now, so it works for sure.

Comment: Are you able to share a link to the actual site you're dealing with (assuming this is something publicly available). What you're describing seems a little odd, so you might find people are able to help better if they can see the real scenario you're describing.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot share the whole source or site, but i should be able to give everything related to my question, so if there is something which I forgot, please tell me. In addition, let me tell you I have not omitted anything in the relevant parts i posted. But, maybe it would also help to see what the links look like. Here's an example: <a href="javascript:b(35486,'455a43e89');">Link</a>

Comment: Your form.action is appending a .txt to the end of the URL. That is probably not what you want unless you somehow have your web server configured to process .txt files as some sort of script. In the <form> element, it is set to a b.php but in the script you are changing it to .txt.

Comment: the .txt is actually some irrelevant file with some data or instructions i want to download and save somewhere. There are no scripts or code of any sort in the .txt . The problem is that the action is changed depending on which link i click, i.e. on which .txt i want to download. The default b.php just leads to the error page telling me to use the "POST" method if I want to download a file.

Comment: I take it you don't have access to the server-side code, or at least, not the ability to change it. What's a bit confusing is that a POST, as the name implies, is normally used to submit information to a server, rather than to download information from a file.

If it's a one-off task that you want to achieve, and if you're comfortable with the command line, I'd suggest you read about the 'curl' utility, which enables you to send arbitrary HTTP requests, and would let you do what you're describing. If you're on Windows, it might be a bit trickier to set up curl, but I think it's possible.

Comment: Re-reading your question, are you able to elaborate a bit on the .txt file - do you definitely know that it is a file that exists, and that it has the information you want? Can you maybe explain a bit more about what the information is in the file, or provide a bit more context around the service that you're using?

Comment: Like I said above, the .txt is completely irrelevant to what I want to do, and it does exist. It could as well be a .xdoc or .pdf or anything. I just want to save it. Anyway, maybe this point was too confusing, but thank you for the help. I solved my problem now and edited my question with the answer.